# How to share imports between components in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, inheritance, components

How to avoid retyping different imports all around different components. 
Like if App has 
 import A from a
And Component needs this import, but I dont want to rewrite the it any every component.

Comment: Nope, you will need it. And the editor should make the majority works for you, which mean it shouldn't be an issue for developers

Comment: i believe you are referencing to vue since there you can import globally and can use anywhere. but here you have to import

Comment: I would recommend using import statements. This helps webpack for tree shaking and code splitting, which will help increasing your react app's performance